# Blackberry, QRs, and video

Tags: blackberry, youtube, mp4, qr-code

I've been asked to create a QR image that, on being scanned by a smartphone, will play a short 2-minute video. The video is currently in .mp4 format, but the format can change. The video playback works fine on iPhone however I'm having some problems with the BlackBerry Bold.

When the user scans the QR code the phone directs them to a URL. Right now the URL they are directed to is `http://domain.com/video.mp4`. However when the user attempts to access this page they get a 413 Error "Entity too large". Basically, too much is being pushed to the client.

Reading the BlackBerryForums.com.au thread titled ["Request Entity Too Large"](http://www.blackberryforums.com.au/forums/general-bes-discussion/284-request-entity-too-large.html), I see you need to increase the allowed request size. But the user is able to play YouTube videos perfectly fine on their blackberry! WHY? is the youtube video size smaller? What format is YouTube using? Why does YouTube work, when my method doesn't?

I know the obvious solution here is to use YouTube as a hoster and embed the video but I am told I cannot use this quick and easy solution.

Comment: If the question itself is not related to QR codes (and it is not), don't title/tag it as if it were.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that YouTube streams the video.  What you're trying to do is get the user to download the whole video file.

You may need to get a streaming server so that the video can be played.

Alternatively, reduce the filesize of the file by reducing the video resolution and bitrate, make sure the sound is mono and low bitrate as well.